# Separating date,month,year from d/m/y and storing them in three variables using php

Tags: php

Here is the $fdate variable which contains date in the format(dd-M-Y)
so how can i store them separately into three variables...

```
$fdate = $_POST['fdate'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this

if the format is like dd-M-Y

```
$newdate=explode("-",$fdate);
$day=$newdate[0];
$month=$newdate[1];
$year=$newdate[2];
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if its in format (dd-m-y) then use

list($date,$month,$year)=explode('-',$fdate);
```